# Swift / code refactoring / how to add parameters to a UIView

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following UIView extension to add a background.

```
extension UIView {
func addBackground() {
    // screen width and height:
    let width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
    let height = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height

    let imageViewBackground = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height))
    imageViewBackground.image = UIImage(named: "index_clear")
    imageViewBackground.clipsToBounds = true

    // you can change the content mode:
    imageViewBackground.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
    self.addSubview(imageViewBackground)
    self.sendSubviewToBack(imageViewBackground)
}}
```

I call it with

```
    self.view.addBackground()
```

What's the best practise to make the extension generic? I want to change the picture like this:

```
    self.view.addBackground("index_clear")
```

or

```
    self.view.addBackground("other_background_image")
```

Help is very appreciated.

Comment: What about adding a parameter to the method? `func addBackground(imageName: String)`

Comment: Note that that has nothing to do with the general meaning of "generic" in terms of the programming language. It is more about introducing a parameter - which is a VERY basic task - what is your actual question? Just add a parameter to the function.

Comment: I have changed the headline. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: I have edited the question and the headline again. hope the downvote stops now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
extension UIView {
func addBackground(imgName : String) {
    // screen width and height:
    let width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
    let height = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height

    let imageViewBackground = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height))
    imageViewBackground.image = UIImage(named: imgName)
    imageViewBackground.clipsToBounds = true

    // you can change the content mode:
    imageViewBackground.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
    self.addSubview(imageViewBackground)
    self.sendSubviewToBack(imageViewBackground)
}}
```

Comment: works perfect. thank you very much I just wasnt totally sure about the syntax

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid breaking any existing implementations within your code, you can take the default parameter approach and do something like this:

```
extension UIView {
    func addBackground(imageName: String = "index_clear") {
        // screen width and height:
        let width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
        let height = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height

        let imageViewBackground = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height))
        imageViewBackground.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        imageViewBackground.clipsToBounds = true

        // you can change the content mode:
        imageViewBackground.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
        self.addSubview(imageViewBackground)
        self.sendSubviewToBack(imageViewBackground)
    }
}


// You can continue to use it like so
myView.addBackground() // uses index_clear

// or
myView.addBackground("index_not_clear") // uses index_not_clear
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help and effort, but the first answer basically did it for me.